# Вывод популярных тегов

Tags: php

В БД есть несколько записей, в которых есть ячейка `tags`, содержит теги, разделенные запятыми.

Необходимо сделать вывод этих тегов, сортируя по кол-ву повторений.
Сразу же столкнулся с проблемой, что выводимые теги имеют следующую запись:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [tags] => база, базы, валид ) [1] => Array ( [tags] => стим ксго, стим, ксго ) )
```

Видим, что количество вложенных МАССИВОВ зависит от количества найденных строк, для этого я составил следующий запрос:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM topics WHERE tags is NOT NULL";
$res = $pdo->query($sql);
$res2 = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Переменная `$res2['total']` будет содержать количество найденных строк, где есть теги.

Выбираю все теги из БД:

```
$select_tags = "SELECT tags FROM topics WHERE tags is NOT NULL";
$select_tags_result = $pdo->query($select_tags);
$tags = $select_tags_result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Надо как-то вывести все теги, придумал такую конструкцию, объясните, пожалуйста, что не так:

```
  while ($i < $res['total']) {
    $i++;
    $tags = explode(", ", $tags[$i]['tags']);
    foreach ($tags as $key => $value) {
        echo '<a href="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</a> ';
    }
}
```

Выполняется цикл, пока переменная `$i` не будет больше, чем количество найденных строк (`$res['total']`), далее удаляем из переменной `$tags[$i]` все пробелы и запятые и выводим через `foreach` сами теги.

Comment: У вас в корне неверный подход к построению системы тегов.

Comment: А зачем вы вообще заранее получаете количество. Если у вас все строки потом выбираются в массив, не проще ли использовать count($tags) или вообще перебирать его foreach что бы еще про индексы в массиве не думать

Comment: Да, можно count($tags) использовать, не подумал

Comment: Вам нужно привязывать теги к статье (или что там у Вас), как много-ко-многим (many-to-many). Это будет более правильное построение базы (четвертая нормальная форма и всё такое), и обрабатывать данные, далее, Вам будет намного проще.

Comment: @A1essandro, так и сделано, на странице добавления новой темы есть поле "Введите метки", это поле не обязательно. Может, в будущем будет автогенерация тегов из тайтла и текста самой темы, но это потом. Сейчас нужно именно так.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, объясните, что не так-то, пожалуйста.

Comment: $tags['0']['tags'] - выводит все теги как положено из первой найденной строки в БД, что не так-то с циклом?

Comment: Смотрите комментарий @A1essandro выше. Тэг, это отдельная сущность. А связи многие-ко-многим позволят вам мгновенно выбрать из базы только те теги, которые нужно. Без всяких костылей в коде приложения.

Comment: @grisha2217 нужен справочник тегов. просто тег-id: база:1, базы:2, валид:3. и таблица связи где будет только 2 поля topic_id, tag_id. Названия или id тегов через запятую, как у вас сейчас можно использовать только для ускорения выборки статей из базы, что бы при выводе конкретной статьи не лазить в теги. А для аналити и поиска по тегам пользоватся таблицей с id. И кстати у вас сейчас foreach странный, он видимо должен быть `foreach ($tags[$i] as $key => $value) {` а то вы зачем то для каждого топика опять все топики сейчас перебираете

Comment: @Mike , да, таблицу нужно несомненно делать!

Ваша правка мне помогла + сделал выше:
$tags[$i] = explode(", ", $tags[$i]['tags']);